# Akka Persistence - AtLeastOnceDelivery: How to get unlimited number of unconfirmed messages without running out of memory

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

We are using a AtLeastOnceDelivery persistent actor. We are getting a huge volume of unconfirmed messages and this is causing an OutOfMemoryError if this number is too large.

Is there a way we can configure the AtLeastOnceDelivery actor to keep the unconfirmed messages on disk rather than keeping them all in memory until they are confirmed?

Or better is there an alternative to AtLeastOnceDelivery that gets around this limitation?

Comment: Just want to add we have played around with the max number of unconfirmed messages setting. Although reducing this value prevents an OutOfMemoryError it does however results in subsequent messages being discarded. We would like to have a solution where the unconfirmed messages are not kept in memory, but constantly flushed out to file without any loss of messages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tune `AtLeastOnceDelivery` trait to only persist on disk and not keep the information in memory. `AtLeastOnceDelivery` follows similar semantics as persistent actors: the deliverable messages are be backed to a Akka persistence backend and kept in memory for fast access. The in-memory storage is [hardcoded to the trait](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-persistence/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/AtLeastOnceDelivery.scala#L179).

If you have trouble keeping the memory usage in bounds, perhaps you should investigate why that is happening and how to solve it. It seems to me that the actor that keeps running out of memory is not getting responses to its message deliveries fast enough, thus deliverable work keeps piling up.

There are a couple of tricks you can try to speed the message processing. You can try optimising individual components in your message processing to be faster, or you can try parallelising the message processing using techniques such as the [Router actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html#a-router-actor). However, sometimes these tricks might not be enough to get the processing fast enough, which is when you need to consider controlling how messages are brought to the actor for processing.

Instead of the actor accepting all messages coming at it, you could [make the actor pull the work](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern) instead. There are many ways you can implement this pattern, but they have a common premise: instead of dumping all the messages on actors directly, you store the messages to a database (or something that can handle huge volumes of data), and then have worker actors pull and work on the stored messages as fast as they can. I don't think there are many off-the-shelf solutions for the pattern, so you probably have to do a bit of work on implementing the solution yourself.

Comment: @Jaako thank you for your answer. You are spot-on on many of the points you made. Looks like we may have to implement a mechanism to either pull the work or back pressure somehow.